# Scaling weights in multi attribute decisions

Tags: weights

I have a set of attributes that make up a feature (e.g 'Accommodation' in the sample below), each attribute has a weight range specific to the feature as per the picture.

The intention is to have each attribute to take a real number value, apply a function that ensures that the each attribute weight range is applied to the real number and all attribute weights sum up to 1 at feature level.

Each feature would then go through the same process, i.e. take the real number and apply the function for weight range to get to the final decision value.

What is the correct mathematical approach/formula for this? Added kudos for an illustration in Excel or R.

[image: Weighted decision sample]